# ERROR in Cannot read property 'loadChildren' of undefined

Tags: angular6, webpack-4

Webpack compilation fails throwing Cannot read property 'loadChildren' of undefined.

This Happens when i try to load routes from some function like below

```
export const routes: Routes = getRoutes();

function getRoutes() {
    return [{ path: 'homepage', component: HomeComponent }];
}
```

When i export routes normally the webpack compilation will be successful.like below,

```
export const routes: Routes = [{ path: 'homepage', component: HomeComponent }];
```

And am mounting these routes in lazy loaded module.

Answer (score 1):

As a guess, the `getRoutes` function should be exported as well. AoT doesn't know how to compile when declaration is hidden.

So try

```
export function getRoutes() {
    return [{ path: 'homepage', component: HomeComponent }];
}
```

Comment: did you find a solution fr this problem

Comment: that worked for me.  I had a `matcher` set on one of my routes, which referenced function that wasn't exported.  After adding the exporter to that referenced function, seems to have gone away.  :)